# Port storyboard to iOS4

Tags: xcode, ios4, storyboard

I'm a fan of Xcode's new storyboarding, but I'm annoyed it won't work on iOS4. I understand why it won't work, because it relies on new classes added to the iOS5 framework. However, it would be cool to be able to port a storyboard back to iOS4 somehow. A tool that outputted xib files for the individual stories, and code generation for segues.

If anyone knows of anyone else doing something in this area, I'd be interested in using it, since my app needs to support iOS4, but I'd like to move forward with Storyboarding. Can i have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 0):

Nope you cant. Ended up gutting the storyboarding and going back to individual xibs.